# Help with completing the proof: Any unbounded sequence is either infinitely large or has a convergent subsequential limit

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

> Given $\{x_n\}$ is an unbounded sequence, prove:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \infty\ \  \text{or}\ \ \lim_{n_k \to \infty} = A
> $$
>   In other words any unbounded sequence either infinitely large or has a convergent subsequence.

---

**Everything before udpate section is wrong.**

Part 1. Proving $|x_n| > M \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \infty$

$\Box$ Start with the definition of an unbounded sequence:
$$
\forall M > 0 \in \Bbb R \ \exists N \in \Bbb N: \forall n > N\implies |x_n| > M
$$

Suppose that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n \ne \infty
$$
That means:
$$
\forall n\in\Bbb N\ \exists C >0 \in\Bbb R : |x_n| < C
$$

Now taking $M^\prime = \max\{M, C\}$ we have that:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
\exists N \in \Bbb N : &\forall n>N \implies &|x_n| > M^\prime \\
&\forall n \in \Bbb N: &|x_n| < M^\prime
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

So we have arrived to a contradiction which means the assumption is wrong and:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \infty
$$
$\Box$

---

Part 2. It's not clear to me how to prove that if unboundedness does not imply infinity limit then it must imply the existence of a convergent subsequence.

Two questions is my mind:

1. Is part 1 correct?
2. How do I proceed with the second part?

---

I'm using the following definition.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = +\infty \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \Bbb N :\forall n > N \implies x_n > \epsilon \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = -\infty \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \Bbb N :\forall n > N \implies x_n < -\epsilon \\
$$
A sequence is considered infinitely large when:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \infty\ \ \text{when}\ \ \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = + \infty \ \ \text{or} \ \ \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = - \infty
$$

---

**Update**.

Looks like i've messed up a lot of things. I will try once again.
As shown in comments and answers the statement holds only in case:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} |x_n| = \infty \iff \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \Bbb N: \forall n > N \implies |x_n| > \epsilon
$$

Consider the following:
$$
\lnot P = \lnot\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n| = \infty \right) \iff \exists \epsilon > 0\ \forall N_1 \in \Bbb N : \exists n > N_1 \land |x_n| < \epsilon
$$

But on the other hand it is given that $x_n$ is unbounded:
$$
Q = \forall M > 0\ \exists N_2 \in \Bbb N : |x_{N_2}| > M
$$

Construct a negative expression for boundedness:
$$
\lnot P = \exists M > 0\ \forall N_2 \in \Bbb N : |x_{N_2}| < M
$$

If $S = \lnot P \implies \lnot Q$ then $S = P \lor \lnot Q$

Let $\epsilon = M$, choose $N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$ then both statements are true and:
$$
\exists \epsilon > 0\ \forall N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}: \exists n > N \land |x_n| < \epsilon
$$

Now either $P$ is true, which would mean $\lim |x_n| = \infty$, or $\lnot Q$ is true which would mean the sequence is bounded and hence contains a convergent subsequence.

Comment: The statement is incorrect. $x_n = (-1)^n\cdot n$ is an unbounded sequence, yet neither of the two properties holds.

Comment: @5xum since english is not my native language the post may contain translation issues, i've added a description of what i use as a definition of "infinitely large sequence"

Comment: No, it's not translation issues. No matter which country you are in, the definition $$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n  = \infty \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \Bbb N :\forall n > N \implies |x_n| > \epsilon
$$ is **wrong**. There is no country or language on Earth where the sequence $-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,\dots$ converges to $\infty$. The absolute values should not be in the definition.

Comment: @5xum you are right, i've messed things up

Comment: $$
\forall M > 0\ \exists N_1 \in \Bbb N : \forall n > N_1 \implies x_n > M
$$ is **not** the definition of "*a sequence is unbounded*", it is the definition of "*the limit of the sequence is $\infty$*"

Comment: HINT. Consider that $\lim_{n\to \infty}|x_n|=\infty$ means that for every  $ r>0,$ the set $\{n:  |x_n|\leq r\}$ is finite . So what happens if $\neg (\lim_{n\to \infty}|x_n|=\infty)?$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thank you for the hint, hopefully now it is valid.

Comment: Why a downvote? If there is something wrong with the question let me know so that I can improve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is incorrect. $x_n = (-1)^n\cdot n$ is an unbounded sequence, yet neither of the two properties holds.

---

Also, your proof is wrong here:

> Suppose that: $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n \ne \infty $$ That means: $$\forall n\in\Bbb N\ \exists C >0 \in\Bbb R : |x_n| < C $$

This is false. **EVERY** sequence satisfies the condition $$\forall n\in\Bbb N\ \exists C >0 \in\Bbb R : |x_n| < C$$ (since you can always set $C=|x_n|+1$) however not every sequence satisfies the condition $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n \ne \infty$$

In fact, the condition $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \infty$$

is written as:

$$\forall C \exists N\forall n:n>N\implies x_n>C$$

which means that the *negation* of that is written as:

$$\exists C\forall N\exists n>N: n>N\land x_n<C$$ which is different from your statement in that there is no absolute value, and the orders of the quantifiers are different.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, i've reworked the OP

Comment: @roman But the statement you are "proving" is still false!

Comment: I do not what to say, this problem is taken from a book i'm solving. I've tried to google-translate the problem statement: "Prove every unbounded sequence is either infinitely large, or has a finite partial limit". Since you say it is wrong in the first place, i guess the only way is to abandon that problem

Comment: @roman The statement is true if you restrict it to positive sequences, or if you define "being infinitely large" as $\lim_{n\to\infty} |x_n| =\infty$, so you might be misunderstanding some part of the problem.